# What is a stub main method?

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point, stub

I have an assignment in my Object Oriented Programming class and I'm having a little confusion with the Project Setup.

So I created a new java application project called "BMIOption". and Within this project, I had to create a package that contains two java classes, "Bmioption" and "BmiRecord".

It says to add a **stub main method** to the "Bmioption" class file and edit the project properties to make "Bmioption" as the main class to run.(I'm assuming instead of the having the "BMIOption" the main class to run).

Can someone explain what a stub main method does and how to implement it? I hope I was clear enough on my confusion.

Answer (score 4):

I expect that it means add the following code to the class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {}
```

It is a stub because it doesn't really do anything, but it allows you to use the class as the entry point to your application. You can subsequently add statements to your code which add useful behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means create a main method in Bmioption class.

if you are using eclipse type main and ctrl+space bar will help you generate it.